# How Can I Change The Name Of My Subdomain in Wordpress Multisite

Tags: multisite, domain

I would like to change my wordpress multisite (main domain and subdomain) subdomain from name1.example.com to name2.example.com.

I have created the new subdomain in cpanel and believed that all I needed to do was copy the files from the current subdomain folder to the new subdomain folder. However, the files for my current subdomain are in the root directory along with my main domain.

Is there a way to make the change?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In your admin dashboard, go to the **my sites->network admin->sites**, edit the site and change the subdomain URL, there.  No need to touch any files.

Comment: what if I do not see my sites and network admin, all I have is "..posts,media,pages,comments.."